# Combine a 2d numpy array grouped by values in a column

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this array:

```
[['Burgundy Bichon Frise' '1' '137']
['Pumpkin Pomeranian' '1' '182']
['Purple Puffin' '1' '125']
['Wisteria Wombat' '1' '109']
['Burgundy Bichon Frise' '2' '168']
['Pumpkin Pomeranian' '2' '141']
['Purple Puffin' '2' '143']
['Wisteria Wombat' '2' '167']
['Burgundy Bichon Frise' '3' '154']
['Pumpkin Pomeranian' '3' '175']
['Purple Puffin' '3' '128']
['Wisteria Wombat' '3' '167']]
```

The first index contains the names of an animal, the second is the region it's located in, and the 3rd is the population. I need to get the mean of the species in each region and get the max and min of each species in each region. So for "Purple Puffins" the mean should be (125+143+128)/3 = **132**.

I'm very confused on how I can get the numpy array to count only the population per region.

Would separating this 2d array into multiple 2d arrays be better or easier?

Comment: This is a numpy array of strings?

Comment: The mean of each species in each region is rather strange here however, since here it looks like every animal-region tupple occurs exactly once.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yeah, but I need, at least, the 3rd column to be ints. And as for the mean of each species. I mean in each region the mean of the same species. So the mean for "Purple Puffins" in all regions should be 132. Apologies for the miswording.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks more like a task for pandas, we can first construct a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['Burgundy Bichon Frise','1','137'],
    ['Pumpkin Pomeranian','1','182'],
    ['Purple Puffin','1','125'],
    ['Wisteria Wombat','1','109'],
    ['Burgundy Bichon Frise','2','168'],
    ['Pumpkin Pomeranian','2','141'],
    ['Purple Puffin','2','143'],
    ['Wisteria Wombat','2','167'],
    ['Burgundy Bichon Frise','3','154'],
    ['Pumpkin Pomeranian','3','175'],
    ['Purple Puffin','3','128'],
    ['Wisteria Wombat','3','167']], columns=['animal', 'region', 'n'])
```

Next we can convert the `region` and `n` to numbers, this will make calculating statistics easier:

```
df.region = pd.to_numeric(df.region)
df.n = pd.to_numeric(df.n)
```

Finally we can perform a `.groupby(..)` and then calculate an aggregate, like:

```
>>> df[['animal', 'n']].groupby(('animal')).min()
                         n
animal                    
Burgundy Bichon Frise  137
Pumpkin Pomeranian     141
Purple Puffin          125
Wisteria Wombat        109
>>> df[['animal', 'n']].groupby(('animal')).max()
                         n
animal                    
Burgundy Bichon Frise  168
Pumpkin Pomeranian     182
Purple Puffin          143
Wisteria Wombat        167
>>> df[['animal', 'n']].groupby(('animal')).mean()
                                n
animal                           
Burgundy Bichon Frise  153.000000
Pumpkin Pomeranian     166.000000
Purple Puffin          132.000000
Wisteria Wombat        147.666667
```

**Edit**: obtaining the minimum row *per* animal

We can use `idxmin`/`idxmax` to obtain the index numbers for the smallest/largest rows *per* animal, and then use `df.iloc[..]` to obtain these rows, like:

```
>>> df.ix[df.groupby(('animal'))['n'].idxmin()]
                  animal  region    n
0  Burgundy Bichon Frise       1  137
5     Pumpkin Pomeranian       2  141
2          Purple Puffin       1  125
3        Wisteria Wombat       1  109
>>> df.ix[df.groupby(('animal'))['n'].idxmax()]
                  animal  region    n
4  Burgundy Bichon Frise       2  168
1     Pumpkin Pomeranian       1  182
6          Purple Puffin       2  143
7        Wisteria Wombat       2  167
```

Here `0, 5, 2, 3` (for `idxmin`) are the "row numbers" of the dataframe.

Comment: For the min, max, and mean, how do I know what region those numbers are located in? For example, the min for "Burgundy Bichon Frise" is 137 in region 1, but the code doesn't tell me so.

Comment: @FunGryphon: see edit. As for the average, there is of course no region (well the mean is not "attached" to a specific region).

Comment: So, say I wanted only one max value out of all regions. How would I pick that out? If I wanted to get Pumpkin Pomeranians from the max values?

Comment: You filter `df.ix[df[df.animal == 'Pumpkin Pomeranian']['n'].idxmin()]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to convert the data `a` into a 2D table using numpy:

```
>>> unqr, invr = np.unique(a[:, 0], return_inverse=True)
>>> unqc, invc = np.unique(a[:, 1], return_inverse=True)
# initialize with nans in case there are missing values
# these are then treated correctly by nanmean etc.:
>>> out = np.full((unqr.size, unqc.size), np.nan)
>>> out[invr, invc] = a[:, 2]
>>> 
# now we have a table
>>> out
array([[137., 168., 154.],
       [182., 141., 175.],
       [125., 143., 128.],
       [109., 167., 167.]])
# with rows
>>> unqr
array(['Burgundy Bichon Frise', 'Pumpkin Pomeranian', 'Purple Puffin',
       'Wisteria Wombat'], dtype='<U21')
# and columns
>>> unqc
array(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U21')
>>> 
# find the mean for 'Purple Puffin':
>>> np.nanmean(out[unqr.searchsorted('Purple Puffin')])
132.0
# find the max for region '2'
>>> np.nanmax(out[:, unqc.searchsorted('2')])
168.0
```